# I can't configure WSO2 API Manager at EC2 instance of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager, amazon-ec2

I can't configure WSO2 API Manager  at EC2 instance  of AWS . I install jdk & Set JAVA_HOME at the particular EC2 instance .Then I using sh command to stated the service , service is stated. But I can't display any response at browser when I hit

> https://IP:9443

I already successful configure WSO2 API Manager at my local machine.
version of WSO2 API Manager is 1.9.1

Comment: You may need to check [Clustering API Manager in Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48272571)

Comment: Url should be like https://IP:9443/carbon